# libssl|openssl | SSL connect taking too much time

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl, network-programming

I have an old application that uses Apache Axis C++ its is calling a webservice  and it calls ssl23_read_bytes and seems the it is stuck in that function , we receive proper response after 63 seconds exactly.
I took a gcore to see the function that is taking time and it is stuck here :

```
#0  0x00cd5430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00415663 in __read_nocancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x002ec798 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
#3  0x002ea78e in BIO_read () from /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
#4  0x001b51ec in ssl23_read_bytes () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
#5  0x001b4015 in ssl23_connect () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
#6  0x001c824b in SSL_connect () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
#7  0x00de1f05 in SecureChannel::Open (this=0x118d7dc0, p_RemoteNode=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/../share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 555, in to_string
    reptype = gdb.lookup_type (str (realtype) + '::_Rep').pointer ()
RuntimeError: No type named std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep.
, p_RemoteEnd=8443, urlForProxyConnection=0x0)
```

Comment: What is your service connecting too?  Because it's the **server** that's slow.

Comment: Could be network/routing related, try `nc -z` on the port (8443 as it appears to be) you use to see what happens.